# Action Pack Subscription License Keys - Physical vs Virtual

Tags: action, subscription, pack

I've noticed on my Action Pack Subscription there are new license keys for Windows Operating Systems that are labeled Physical and Virtual. There is no documentation on the site about what the differences are for those keys.

I called Microsoft and got the run around. Eventually, the MS tech emailed me a snippet of text that described what the difference between the keys were. Obviously the MS tech needs to go back to school, she sent me a description on the difference between virtual keys on the keyboard.

Does anyone have a clue as to what the difference is? I've searched Google, but can't find any real straight answers. I would like to use some of those keys on production servers, but am hesitant.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  I asked the same question.  The virtual key licenses are for installation on virtual machines.

Comment: The virtual keys are only for server 2008. Server 2008 has Hyper-V built in, which allows one more installation of server 2008. The virtual key is for that installation.